# Is it possible to make my button active when clicked?

Tags: php

I had this separate button, and if i click the first button, it will become active, and at the same time if i click the second button, the first button will not become active, instead the second button will become active. One problem that i try is that, i cannot make my button in list li, because i had a different style for the button.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <form action="grocery.php" method="POST">
    <div class="btn-change" role="group">
       <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button style="border-radius: 20px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="req" id="req">Purc Details</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
           <button style="border-radius: 20px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="sold" id="sold">Cust Details</button>
         </div>
     </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a php related issue. If you would like to change the "active", you are implicitly saying that you want to change the style or the class of the button right?

If that's the case here is a jquery listener for you that implements such behavior for one button

```
$("#req_rep").click(function () { 
    $("#req_rep").attr("class", "class-of-active-button");
    // or you can $("#req_rep").css(property, value);

});
```

You may also consider changing the type submit, so you can see what happens on your page without submitting the form and ending by refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you exactly want and I really don't see the use of this visual effect as the form will submit right away when one of those buttons is clicked because of `type="submit"`.

So, I'll suggest you no more make them form submission triggers by changing their type to `button`, and create a hidden type input that will actually hold the type of "details". Like this:

```
<form id="grocery-form" ...>
  // ...
  <input name="details_type" type="hidden" />
  <div class="btn-group details-type" ...>
    <button type="button" class="btn ..." data-value="req">Purc Details</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn ..." data-value="sold">Cust Details</button>
  </div>
  // ...
  <button ...>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
var form = document.getElementById("grocery-form"),
  detailsTypeButtons = form.querySelectorAll(".details-type button");

detailsTypeButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    // Set the value to a field than can actually be submitted with the form
    form.details_type.value = this.getAttribute("data-value");

    // Removing class of active button on any of these buttons if there is
    detailsTypeButtons.forEach(function(button_) {
      button_.classList.remove("class-of-active-button");
    });

    // Adding class of active button on this button
    this.classList.add("class-of-active-button");
  };
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps!